# Python do not works from command line

Tags: python, path, python-2.7

I've installed Python 2.7 on windows in folder C:\Python27

Added path to system PATH variable - C:\Python27

So I'm trying to start it from command line, but it works only in its native folder:

```
C:\Python27> python
```

And do not works from any other folder

System can not recognize it. I did reboot after adding it to PATH.

Can somebody tell me, what do I do wrong?

Best Regards, Ahmed.

p.s.

Here is my PATH

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WIN
DOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\server\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\MKVtoolnix; C
:\Program Files\ZF\bin; C:\Python27
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `path` in the console?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a separator in the path? try adding it as first in path.

Comment: Made an update. You can see it now

Comment: Not a windows user, but C**<space>**:\Program Files\ZF\bin;  seems to be problematic... can you remove that space and retest ?

Comment: I’m not sure how exactly Windows takes the format, but try removing the *space* in front of the Python path…

Comment: In all fairness to this question, where to set Windows paths never ceases to be a mystery to me, and I developed on Windows for over a decade. Maybe they've improved since XP. In other words, I'm not surprised there are spaces in the paths and a missing semi colon. It's easy to miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whitespace before the `C:\Python27` and add a semicolon at the end.
As per pydave, you should also remove the other whitespace before `C:\Program Files\ZF\bin`

Comment: Should also remove the space before `C:\Program Files\ZF\bin`